# Como abrir uma página específica do PDF com o Xamarin (iOS)?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, pdf

Eu uso o seguinte código para abrir um documento PDF.

Eu gostaria de saber como abrir o PDF em uma página específica, porque toda vez que eu executo o código, o documento é aberto no começo.

```
public void OpenFile(string targetPath)
{
    try
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            QLPreviewItemFileSystem prevItem = new QLPreviewItemFileSystem(_name, targetPath);
            QLPreviewController previewController = new QLPreviewController();
            previewController.DataSource = new PreviewControllerDS(prevItem);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```